# Задача на запись данных в файл

Tags: c#, .net

У меня есть файл input.txt, так же у меня есть массив, в который пользователь должен записать любое количество чисел от 1 до 31. Задача такова: записать в файл две строки, в первой строке количество элементов массива, а во второй строке сам массив. То есть должно получиться как-то так:

```
5
3 4 5 2 3
```

Вот мой код:

```
var input = "Input.txt";
var array = new int[] { int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) };
File.WriteAllText(input, array.Length + Environment.NewLine + string.Join(" ", array));
```

Проблема в том, что когда я ввожу цифры с консоли, появляется ошибка:

```
System.FormatException: Входная строка имела неверный формат.
```

Я пробовал изменить тип данных массива на `string`:

```
var input = "Input.txt";
var array = new string[] { Console.ReadLine() };
File.WriteAllText(input, array.Length + Environment.NewLine + string.Join(" ", array));
```

Но в итоге, так как это строковый массив, на выходе выводилась его длина, а именно `1` потому что цифры записывались в одну строку:

```
1
3 4 5 2 3
```

Помогите решить эту задачу. Заранее спасибо

Comment: `когда я ввожу цифры с консоли, появляется ошибка` быть того не может, так как `int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())`. Вы вводите не число

Comment: я понял, вы вводите `3 4 5 2 3` и пытаетесь это конвертировать в число.

Comment: `var array = new int[] { int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) };` ===> `var array = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(x=>int.Parse(x)).ToArray();`

Comment: чуть короче `int[] array = Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(int.Parse).ToArray();`